# `open` does not create the file

Tags: python

I am working on a `Tkinter` app.
I want to add premium features to it, I will sell an `exe` file that will generate a premium code.

here is the script:

```
import requests
import os
import random
from pathlib import Path

url = 'a website with all of the premium codes in a txt file'

r = requests.get(url)

code = list(map(str, r.text.split()))
appdata = os.getenv("APPDATA")
data = Path(f"{appdata}\\premiumaccess.txt")

if not data.is_file():
    open(f"{appdata}premiumaccess.txt" ,'a')

with open(f"{appdata}\\premiumaccess.txt", 'r') as file:
    if '1' in file:
        print("You already claimed your premium code...")
    else:
        print(f'{random.choice(code)}\n\nThis is your AccTools premium code! do not share it with anyone, have fun!')
        with open(f"{appdata}\\premiumaccess.txt", 'w') as file:
            file.truncate()
            file.write("1")
```

The code gives me the premium code, but does not create any file called `premiumaccess` and writes data in it.

Please help me.

(again, sorry if my English is bad, this is not my main language, ty and sorry)

Comment: By the way, you are already using `pathlib.Path` for `data`. So you can open the file just like `data.open(...)` or `open(data)`.

Comment: Call close on the file you are trying to create an empty version of `open(f"{appdata}premiumaccess.txt" ,'a').close()`

Comment: Since you already have a ```Path``` object, you can create the file with ```data.touch()```

Comment: `if not data.is_file():
    with data.open('premiumaccess.txt') as f:
        f.close()` i tried this, still nothing @BoseongChoi @sj95126

Comment: still nothing, @AndrewAllaire, maybe python can not access the `apddata` folder? idk

Comment: I've accessed window's AppData in python before. To debug this just do one tiny step at a time, for example have a script that does nothing else but create that empty file (also using the Pathlib touch method that sj95126 suggested is probably cleanest way).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is here:

```
if not data.is_file():
    open(f"{appdata}premiumaccess.txt" ,'a')
```

Missing the backash

I suggest use a variable for the path with `os.path.join`:

```
file_path = os.path.join(os.getenv("APPDATA"), "premiumaccess.txt")
```

Comment: `data = os.path.join(os.getenv("APPDATA"), "acctoolspremiumaccess.txt")

if not data:
    open(f"acctoolspremiumaccess.txt", 'a').close()`
still isnt working :(

Comment: use the variable `file_path` directly

Comment: wdym by directly? @user16822867

Comment: in your code the file premiumaccess.txt is repeated so just use file_path

Answer (score 0):

Use the context manager for manipulating your text files. That way your files are properly closed.

Comment: this is the deafult python `open`, if that what you mean

Comment: What i meant is after your first if statement, instead of calling open() directly, you can create the file using: with open(filename, 'a') as file: pass.    That way a file is created if it doesn't exist. And its closed properly until you need it again. 

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).